# Unable to specify Out T in my IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm following the NerdDinner tutorial for MVC and have a question about setting up my repository.  Here's what I have so far...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace BusinessReviews.Models
{
    public class ReviewsRepository
    {
        private BusinessReviewsDataContext db = new BusinessReviewsDataContext();


        public IQueryable GetAllBusinesses()
        {
            return db.Businesses;
        }
    }

}
```

I know that my IQueryable should specify T.  In the tutorial they put the table name where the T is, which in their case was "Dinner".  For my application I think it should be "Business".  Unfortunately Visual Studio is not recognizing the Business class.  Any ideas on what could be wrong?

*Edit --- per comment below, here's what I am trying to write

```
public IQueryable<Business> GetAllBusinesses()
{
return db.Businesses;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand -- your example just has `IQueryable` without any type arguments at all.  Can you show us the code you are *trying* to write?

Comment: See above.  My issue is with the <Business> part.  Intellisense won't let me type "Business".  Maybe it's a namespace issue.  I don't know.

Comment: What error occurs when you include `<Business>` and attempt to compile? Which line does that error point to?

Comment: @hughesdan: Double check your namespaces to ensure you are including the appropriate one. Folders are the most common reason for problems, since they are automatically added as part of the namespace. If not ignore intellisense and add it manually and see what error is raised.

Comment: Where is the type `Business` defined? Have you included a `using` statement for that namespace?

Comment: Jim, Business is defined in my Linq2Sql dbml.  I dragged a table by that name onto the design surface.  But I can't access it.  Guvante, I'll try as you suggest.

Comment: @Guvante, I did as you suggested and the error points to that same line.  "Unknown Type Business"

Comment: @hughesdan: You should be able to expand the dbml and see a designer.cs file. This should contain the generated class that you can deduce the proper namespace from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the error "Unknown type *_*_" is caused by namespace problems. Make sure you are including the appropriate namespaces. When working with generated code it is helpful to look at the generated classes by examining the designer.cs files. There may also be instances where the name isn't what you expected for some reason.

Comment: designer.cs shows that the namespace is BusinessReviews.Models. That's what I'm using above also.

Comment: @hughesdan: Are they part of the same project?

Comment: Yes.  Both my dbml and my repository class are in the Models folder of the same project.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was.  When I looked at the properties on my dbml the Context namespace was specified but the Entity namespace was empty.  I added the missing namespace and everything worked.  Guvante - I'll accept your answer since you were correct about the namespace thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify an `out T` when defining an interface. What you are defining is a method.

```
public interface IMyInterface<out T>
{
    T GetSomething();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.  Have a look at ScottGu's repository here http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm.  It's the same as mine (I think).